# DHCP server not setting correct DNS on Draytek router

Tags: networking, router, dns, draytek

We have a Draytek Vigor router and are having problems with the DNS updating on the client computers.

I have set the DHCP server on the router as this:

Enable Server

Start IP Address : 10.0.10.10

IP Pool Count: 200

Gateway IP: 10.0.10.1

Lease Time: 86400

Primary IP Address: 10.0.0.13

Secondary IP Address: blank

We are using the DNS of our parent office which is also running a draytek router over site to site VPN. We are doing this to enable us to connect the sub office to the Active Directory.

The site to site VPN is working well.

However, the problem we have is that the windows machines are not using the 10.0.0.13 DNS setting but are instead using:

Preferred DNS: 127.0.0.1

Alternate DNS: 10.0.10.57 (this is the IP of the machine).

So when we try to connect the machine to the domain it will not connect since it cannot connect to the parent office DNS server.

No matter what I do to try and either force the DNS on the windows NIC to use 10.0.0.13 or set to use Obtain address automatically it revers back to the settings above.

I have checked the network configuration and it is using the correct DHCP server.

I have also renewed all the leases, rebooted.

I'm at a bit of a loss now how to get the windows machine to use 10.0.0.13 as it's DNS server as per the DHCP config.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Thanks
Carl

Comment: you probably have a DNS proxy running on your machine, like DNScrypt-proxy.exe

Comment: Ah yes, perfect, that's what it is. It turns out our AV was interfering with the DNS setting. Thanks!